# Hover function not working inside iframe

Tags: jquery, html

Hover function not working inside iFrame.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.check').live('hover',function(){
alert(0)
})})
</script>

<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="yes" src="frame.html" width="400"></iframe>
```

//frame html

```
<a class="check" href="javascript:void"> hover me</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: You could simply fix the problem by moving the script inside frame.html

Comment: have you tried using the [sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) attribute?

Answer (score 0):

### IFrame on same domain

I think this is what you are describing...

If your iframe is from the same domain as your code, you can use:

`$("iframe").contents().find('.check')` as your selector.

### IFrame from a different domain

Not possible, please see this question: [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)